# CSS height auto is not working in relative DIV

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I have this code to show `absolute div` into `relative div`.

html:

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="relative">
                    <div class="absolute">Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position. Other content will not be adjusted to fit into any gap left by the element.</div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
               normal text added
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

css:

```
.relative {
    position: relative;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#e1e1e1;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    width: auto;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    margin:0 15px;
}
```

In reality when I set `height:auto` for `relative div` this `div` is not showing. If I set any `height` value ie: `height:150px;` relative `div` it works and shows true. How do I fix this problem ?

demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4onnaoa2/1/)

Comment: replace the code....
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    margin:0 15px;
    height:100%;
}

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this with css, and need to set the height on your outer div with `position:relative` for your inner `position:absolute` to show.

This is because when you set a `<div>` to be position:absolute, the outer container no longer has the concept of its width and height and will not accommodate the space it takes up.

Answer (score 0):

add overflow :hidden; min-height:100px;

```
.relative {
    position: relative;
    height:auto;
    overflow :hidden;
    min-height:100px;
    background-color:#e1e1e1;
}
```

Comment: need to change this portion also .absolute {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    width: auto;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    margin:0 15px;
        overflow: auto;
    height: 100px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Here the trick

CSS

```
.relative {
  position: relative;
    overflow :hidden;
    min-height:100px;
    background-color:#e1e1e1;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    width: auto;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    margin:0 15px;
        overflow: auto;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4onnaoa2/3/)

Set the relative height and absolute height

Comment: i check your demo with FF and see div scroll. i dont need to scroll div